# Finding a generator for the kernel of a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, solution-verification

I am having some trouble understanding the solution to this problem.

**Problem:** Let $\varphi$ denote the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $\varphi(f(x)) = f(1 + \sqrt{2})$. Is the kernel of $\varphi$ a principal ideal? If so, find a generator.

**Solution:**

`Line 1:` We want to find the polynomials $f(x)$ such that $f(1+\sqrt{2}) = 0$.

`Line 2:` Using the canonical embedding of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ into $\mathbb{R}[x]$, we see that $(x - (1+\sqrt{2}))$ would generate the kernel of $\varphi$ in $\mathbb{R}[x]$.

`Line 3:` But then, since $(x - (1+\sqrt{2}))(x - (1-\sqrt{2})) = x^2-2x-1$, and $(x^2-2x-1) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$, we obtain $(x^2-2x-1) \subseteq \ker\varphi$, as an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

`Line 4:` But since $x^2-2x-1$ is primitive and irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, since its roots are $(1\pm\sqrt{2})$, $x^2-2x-1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

`Line 5:` Now suppose that $f(x) \in \ker\varphi \setminus (x^2-2x-1)$.

`Line 6:` By the Euclidean algorithm dividing $f(x)$ by $x^2-2x-1$, we can assume without loss of generality that $f(x) = ax+b$.

`Line 7:` But then, $\varphi(f) = a + a\sqrt{2} + b \ne 0$ unless $a=b=0$, and so we see that $(x^2-2x-1) = \ker\varphi$.

**Here are my questions in order:**

Line 2: What's the simplest way to rephrase it, without the fancy terminology?

Line 3: We obtain $(x^2-2x-1) \subseteq \ker\varphi$, as an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. *Why?*

Line 6: Why use "without loss of generality"? It is not clear enough for me - how can I prove it without using that?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In your definition of the map, you say $\phi(x) = 1+\sqrt{2}$, presumably you don't intend for your homomorphism to be constant? Maybe you mean $\phi(f(x)) = f(1+\sqrt{2})$?

Comment: I was thinking that too. But it is defined this way in Artin's Algebra, and I could not find it listed in the errata.

Comment: I suppose it makes sense if you take it as $x \mapsto 1+\sqrt{2}$ and not $\forall f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, $f(x) \mapsto 1+\sqrt{2}$, but still I think the meaning is $f(x) \mapsto f(1+\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: To define an homomorphism from an `algebra` of polynomials, it's well-known it suffices to specify the images of the indeterminates.

Comment: @Bernard That does make good sense, but I haven't ever seen it written that way. Dummitt and Foote (which is what I used) doesn't do it that way, and when we define mappings $\phi: R\rightarrow S$ and say $r \mapsto s$, usually $r$ is allowed to be any $R$-element, not just a single one. But I can see it as like defining where the generator of a cyclic group goes to determine the homomorphism.

Comment: @walkar: Exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Line 3: This is because $\phi(x^2-2x-1)=0.$

Line 6: Using division algorithm, write $f(x)=g(x)(x^2-2x-1) + r(x)$ for some $g(x), r(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ with deg $r(x) \leq 1.$ Now apply $\phi$ in the above equation. We get $\phi(f(x))=\phi(r(x))$ and $r(x)$ is of the form $ax+b, a, b \in \mathbb Z.$

Comment: In Line 3, why is $(x^2-2x-1)$ an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$? I understand the kernel part.

Comment: The line *"$(x^2-2x-1) \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[x]$"* means that we are considering the element $x^2-2x-1$ as an element of $\mathbb Z[x]$ and we are taking the ideal generated by $x^2-2x-1$ **in** $\mathbb Z[x].$ We are **not** considering it as an ideal in $\mathbb R[x].$

Comment: First of all the way map $\phi$ is defined, it's not clear (at least at the first look) what will be a possible generator of ker $\phi.$ That's why the map was extended to $\mathbb R[x].$ From there, we choose a suitable polynomial as a candidate to be a generator, then come back to $\mathbb Z[x].$ There we prove that it is actually a generator. Once we get a possible generator (in this case $x^2-2x-1$) then our work in $\mathbb R[x]$ is done. After that everything will be done in $\mathbb Z[x].$ This is actually the meaning and necessity of "Line 2."

Comment: In Line $7$, why is $(x^2-2x-1)=\ker\varphi$? It seems like some steps were skipped.

Comment: In Line 7, it says that there is no element in the set ker $\phi \setminus (x^2-2x-1).$ In other words ker $\phi \subseteq (x^2-2x-1).$

Comment: Ok got it. Do you think I can apply the exact same approach in this problem, to a new problem with $1+\sqrt{2}$ replaced by $\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

Line 2: The canonical embedding of $\mathbb{Z}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ is merely $f(x) \mapsto f(x)$, and as $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ this makes perfect sense. We merely view the integer polynomials as real polynomials.

It looks like @Krish answered the other questions.